# Not sure where the core data code should go in the MVC

Tags: ios, database, core-data, model-view-controller, nsmanagedobject

In this app I'm working on, I use core data to store content. I populate the database in the `AppDelegate`'s `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`method. And in the view controller, I'm extracting the required data using a `NSFetchRequest`.

My question is, is the code related to extracting data should be in the view controller? Or should I create separate methods in the `NSManagedObject` subclasses generated for those entities and call them from the view controller?

Can someone please shed some light on this?

Thank you.

Comment: You should create separate model class for it. You can add various methods in that to add/update/fetch core data entity objects. Also you can create shared instance of the same if multiple view controllers requires same data at a time.

Comment: You mean another brand new Model class? Not the `NSManagedObject` subclass, right?

Comment: The viewController is where you usually invoke performFetch to fetch the array of entities (NSManagedObject subclasses> from Core Data. Also the place to update attributes and/or delete objects. Apple provide plenty of sample code for this.

Comment: Just be aware that long processes may block the main thread - so populating your database in didFinishLaunching may result in an unresponsive application unless you do it on a background thread.

Comment: @DuncanGroenewald Thank you. The amount of data is fairly small. I will move the saving process to a separate thread if it shows any signs of lagging in performance.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a model class, which means something like:

```
@interface DataImporter : NSObject
@property(nonatomic, readonly) CoreDataManager *coreDataManager;

 - (id)initWithCoreDataManager:(CoreDataManager *)coreDataManager;

 - (void)importDataWithCompletionCallback:(void (^)())completionBlock;
@end
```

It's not a `NSManagedObject` subclass, but it's an object responsible for importing data into your CoreData store. `importDataWithCompletionCallback` can e.g. create all necessary `NSManagendObject` objects (depending on some JSON) and save them, do it in background, call callback block after completion.

Subclassing `NSManagendObject` is not a good way to follow.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But the data I'm saving is not coming from a web service or anything. Also its not changing. I'm concerned about the `NSManagendObject` subclasses that are created for the Entities in the database. If I put methods to say, get an array of objects of a certain entity, is that bad practice?

Comment: Yeah. You shouldn't add any methods directly to subclasses' files. But you can create a category for your entity subclass.
If you have data in code, it's better to have them structured in some way, e.g. have a class that is a `DataProvider`.